# jquery mobile, call transition from event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

To have JQM apply a transition on a link, we use the following:

```
<a href="index.html" data-transition="pop">I'll pop</a>
```

How do I call a transition form a custom event?

I use:

`window.location.href = href;` to navigate from my custom event.

I can't seem to find anything on the reference material, except for the  markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set up a [default global transition](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html)

You can set up the default global transition like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  //these are the jqm default values for these transition types by the way.
  $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = "pop";
  $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "fade";
});
```

if you're looking for custom transitions for a specific event, you could use this :

```
$.mobile.changePage("yourpage.html", {transition:"slide"});
```

rather than a plain HTML link, or a `window.location=something;`

Comment: I would like to specify my type of transition on demand... I'l either, flip, slide etc for different scenarios.